# Haskell: Expected Laziness, Why is this Evaluated?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, lazy-evaluation, option-type

I have a function `sideH` which runs the risk of `Prelude.head []`.  Hence, I have written it using Maybe, to avoid this:

```
sideH :: Residue -> Maybe (Atom, Atom)
sideH res
    -- Make sure the elements exist
    | nits /= [] && cars /= [] && oxys /= [] = Just (newH1, newH2)
    | otherwise = Nothing where
    ...
```

The above works exactly as expected, without error.  Now, in the function which calls `sideH` (which is not a do construct), I must handle the situation that `sideH` returns `Nothing`:

```
callerFunc :: [Residue] -> Aromatic -> [(Double, Double)]
callerFunc [] _ = []
callerFunc (r:rs) aro
    -- Evaluate only if there is something to evaluate
    | newHs /= Nothing = (newH1Pos, newH2Pos)
    | otherwise = callerFunc rs aro where
    newHs = sideH r
    newH1Pos = atomPos $ fst $ fromJust newHs
    newH2Pos = atomPos $ snd $ fromJust newHs
```

If I try to evaluate `newH1Pos` or `newH2Pos` when `newH = Nothing`, it will fail because `fromJust Nothing` is an error.  However, I expect this to never happen.  I expect the `callerFunc` to evaluate `newHs`, which is either `Just something` or `Nothing`.  If it is `Nothing`, then the `callerFunc` will go to its next step without ever evaluating `newH1Pos` or `newH2Pos`.  This does not appear to be the case.  I get an `*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing` error exactly where I would expect `newHs` to return `Nothing`.

I was asked for more code.  I am trying to come up with a minimum situation that reproduces the error, but in the mean time, here is the complete problematic `callerFunc` code.

```
-- Given a list of residues and an aromatic, find instances where there
--  is a Hydrogen bond between the aromatic and the Hydrogens on Gln or Asn
callerFunc :: [Residue] -> Aromatic -> [(Double, Double)]
callerFunc [] _ = []
callerFunc (r:rs) aro
    -- GLN or ASN case
    | fst delR <= 7.0 && (resName r == gln || resName r == asn) &&
        newHs /= Nothing && snd delR <= 6.0 = 
        [(snd delR, fst delR)] ++ hBondSFinder rs aro
    | otherwise = hBondSFinder rs aro where
    -- Sidechain identifying strings
    gln = B.pack [71, 76, 78]
    asn = B.pack [65, 83, 78]
    -- Get the location of the Hydrogens on the residue's sidechain
    newHs = sideH r
    newH1Pos = atomPos $ fst $ fromJust newHs
    newH2Pos = atomPos $ snd $ fromJust newHs
    -- Get the location of the Nitrogen on the mainchain of the Residue
    ats = resAtoms r
    backboneNPos = atomPos $ head $ getAtomName ats "N"
    hNVect1 = Line2P {lp1 = newH1Pos, lp2 = backboneNPos}
    hNVect2 = Line2P {lp1 = newH2Pos, lp2 = backboneNPos}
    interPoint1 = linePlaneInter (aroPlane aro) hNVect1
    interPoint2 = linePlaneInter (aroPlane aro) hNVect2
    delR = minimum [(interPoint1 `dist` newH1Pos, delr1), 
        (interPoint2 `dist` newH2Pos, delr2)]
    delr1 = interPoint1 `dist` (aroCenter aro)
    delr2 = interPoint2 `dist` (aroCenter aro)
```

I know this is a painful code dump.  I am trying to whittle it down.

Comment: Off topic, but what are you doing that you're using a typesig of `[Residue] -> Aromatic`?

Comment: @amindfv: PDB (protein structure) parsing and data mining.

Comment: Assuming your compiler isn't insanely broken the exception is not from this code fragment.  Perhaps more code, or a minimum program that reproduces this behavior would be helpful.

Comment: @PhilipJF: Alright, thank you.  It is good to know that my Haskell expectation is not completely wrong.  I will try to create a code sample that reproduces the error, without the need for the 12 custom libraries that I am using! :/

Comment: Oh, oh oh!  How very stupid of me!  I think it is because the first guard tests the value of `delR`, and `delR` is defined in terms of `newH1Pos` and `newH2Pos`, so they are indeed evaluated, even if `newHs /= Nothing` is not satisfied.

Comment: By the way, using `(/= [])` and `(/= Nothing)` are bad style: just use pattern matching instead! (In fact, `(/=)` introduces a spurious `Eq` constraint; compare the output of `:t null` and `:t (/= [])` in ghci.)

Comment: However, this creates an interesting problem.  How do I first test for `newHs /= Nothing`, and then only if it passes, then I do the other tests?  Perhaps simply write a wrapper function?

Comment: @thoughtadvances Just move the `newHs /= Nothing` test earlier. `newHs /= Nothing && fst delR <= 7.0 && ...`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Concerning pattern matching: That is interesting, but I am not sure how I would use pattern matching, here, to remove these if statement.

Comment: Never use fromJust and head. Pattern match!

Comment: @augustss: How would a person go about dispensing of the need for both fromJust and head?  Even Daniel Wagner's answer, below, would still require the use of fromJust.  Any function which calls his function will need to take the value out of the Maybe.

Comment: @augustss: Hmm... Maybe I see how:
`func [] = []\n
func (x:xs) = case (stuff) of\n
    (Just _) -> [stuff] ++ fund xs\n
    _ -> Nothing\n
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question (asked in the comments) doesn't fit in a comment: "I am not sure how I would use pattern matching, here, to remove these if statement.".

Like this, for example, though there are still some code smells left that could likely be improved with some additional refactoring:

```
sideH :: Residue -> Maybe (Atom, Atom)
sideH res = case (nits, cars, oxys) of
    (_:_, _:_, _:_) -> Just (newH1, newH2)
    _ -> Nothing
    where
    ...
```

If you have flexible morals, you might try something like this:

```
sideH :: Residue -> Maybe (Atom, Atom)
sideH res = do
    _:_ <- return nits
    _:_ <- return cars
    _:_ <- return oxys
    return (newH1, newH2)
    where
    ...
```

Again, both of these code samples can likely be improved about tenfold if there's a bit more context and code available to make recommendations for.

Comment: There is nothing immoral about `do` notation with the `Maybe` monad.

Comment: @PhilipJF But using `pattern <- return var` instead of `case var of pattern` can be considered immoral.

Comment: @PhilipJF `fail` is immoral, and pattern matches in do-blocks call it when they don't match.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thank you.  This is very interesting.  I will attempt to implement the first method.

Comment: @DanielWagner: `_:_` is very clever.  I see you are treating nits, cars, and oxys as lists of the form (x:xs).

Comment: `fail` is only immoral because Haskell calls `MonadFail` `Monad. pattern matching in `do` is perfectly reasonable in the maybe monad (clear semantics, equational reasoning, safety, etc)